# protractor automation droplist

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am new to Protractor for automation.

I have a scenario where I have a query bar (has a state droplist(dropdown with multiple states - where a combination of states can be selected), Regions and Status (Admitted/Discharged) droplists in a similar way where multiple combinations can be selected.

There is a web table Status which is populated (Admitted and Discharged for different age ranges-10 values) based on the query bar selection.

Currently, I am considering each scenario - for CA, West Region, Admitted/Discharged status (on the query bar) and querying using stored procedure for each table entry. It is working but there are too many scenarios. I am wondering if there is any better way to do it- like looping the droplist for states,region status combination and calculating the query result.

Here is the idea of the code:
- Connect is the stored procedure (hard-coding the values as the UI value is a little bit different than in the stored procedure - the UI value comes as 'NJ, OR, TX' whereas my stored procedure takes 'NJ,OR,TX' as input.

HTML code of dropdown:

```
<filter-dropdown _ngcontent-c7="" class="filter-item__component" _nghost c11="" id="State">
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-item__wrapper">

    <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-item">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-name">State</span>
      <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-select">CA</a>
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__box filter-popup__scroll active">
      <ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter- popup__list">
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link active" title="true">California (CA)</a>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link" title="true">Colorado (CO)</a>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link" title="true">Illinois (IL)</a>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link" title="true">Indiana (IN)</a>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link" title="true">Kansas (KS)</a>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter- popup__item text-left">
          <a _ngcontent-c11="" class="filter-popup__link" title="true">Michigan     (MI)</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</filter-dropdown>
```

Protractor script I tried:

```
describe('check table ', function () {

    it('should select nj,or,tx Admitted Status', function () {

        browser.waitForAngular();
        dmgPageObject.selectnjortsState();


    })
    var tabledata = element(by.css('.table'));
    var rows = tabledata.all(by.tagName("tr"));
    var cells = rows.all(by.tagName("td"));
    var headers = cells.all(by.tagName("th"));



    it('should check header Under 18', function () {

        expect(cells.get(0).getText()).toEqual("Under 18");

    });


    it('checks Under 18 admitted status', function (done) {


        conf2.Connect('NJ,OR,TX', 'Admitted', 'Under 18').then(function
            _onSuccess(_returned) {
            expect(cells.get(1).getText()).toEqual((_returned.recordset[0]
            ['']).toString());
            done();

        }).catch(function _onFailure(err) {
            done.fail(err);

        })
    })

    it('tests dbconnection for under 18 Discharged status', function () {
        expect(cells.get(2).getText()).toEqual("0");

    })

    it('should check 18-40 header', function () {

        expect(cells.get(3).getText()).toEqual("18 - 40");

    });

    it('checks 18-40 admitted status', function (done) {

        conf2.Connect('NJ,OR,TX', 'Admitted', '18 - 40').then(function
            _onSuccess(_returned) {
            expect(cells.get(4).getText()).toEqual((_returned.recordset[0]
            ['']).toString());
            done();

        }).catch(function _onFailure(err) {
            done.fail(err);

        })
    })

    it('tests dbconnection for 18-40 Discharged status', function () {
        expect(cells.get(5).getText()).toEqual("0");

    })

    it('should check 41-65 header', function () {

        expect(cells.get(6).getText()).toEqual("41 - 65");

    });

    it('checks 41-65 admitted status', function (done) {
        conf2.Connect('NJ,OR,TX', 'Admitted', '40 - 60').then(function
            _onSuccess(_returned) {
            expect(cells.get(7).getText()).toEqual((_returned.recordset[0]
            ['']).toString());
            done();

        }).catch(function _onFailure(err) {
            done.fail(err);

        })
    })

    it('checks 41-65 discharged status', function (done) {
        expect(cells.get(8).getText()).toEqual("0");
        done();
    })


    it('should check 66-85 header', function () {

        expect(cells.get(9).getText()).toEqual("66 - 85");

    });

    it('checks 66-85 admitted status', function (done) {

        conf2.Connect('NJ,OR,TX', 'Admitted', '66 - 85').then(function
            _onSuccess(_returned) {
            expect(cells.get(10).getText()).toEqual((_returned.recordset[0]
            ['']).toString());
            done();

        }).catch(function _onFailure(err) {
            done.fail(err);

        })
    })

    it('checks 66-85 discharged status', function () {
        expect(cells.get(11).getText()).toEqual("0");
    })

    it('should check 86+ header', function () {

        expect(cells.get(12).getText()).toEqual("86+");

    });

    it('checks 86+ admitted status', function (done) {
        conf2.Connect('NJ,OR,TX', 'Admitted', '86+').then(function
            _onSuccess(_returned) {
            expect(cells.get(13).getText()).toEqual((_returned.recordset[0]
            ['']).toString());
            done();

        }).catch(function _onFailure(err) {
            done.fail(err);

        })
    })

})
```

Comment: The actual thing that you're trying to accomplish is unclear. If you are trying to iterate through all the changes, pull the result from wherever the actual value is calculated, and then assert that that is the displayed value, then yeah! Go for it!

Comment: I am actually trying to validate the table entries(thru queries) and assert that they are correct based on the selection in the drop down, scenario would be select states :NJ,OR,TX click apply and then table is populated for admitted/discharged in the age ranges .I have 15 states in the droplist and not clear as to how to iterate and do this functionality. Could you help with any code. The issue is every entry in the table is the result of a qury not a getText() compare , so unsure how to implement this

Comment: I can't help with code because: 1. I don't have access to your code and can't run it. 2. I'm really busy and wouldn't have the time to put into actually debugging your problem. It seems to me like your main question is "How can I iterate in the states of the dropdown list?"

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence in your comment: "The issue is every entry in the table is the result of a query not a getText() compare , so unsure how to implement this"